# Setting animation to move in reverse & showing shape from class when button is clicked

Tags: java, animation, button, javafx, reverse

I am working on a javafx program to create three buttons which are "circle", "ellipse" and "reverse". The circle button is the first thing shown when the program is run, the reverse button is supposed to correspond with the movement of the rectangle around the circle. I am having trouble getting the reverse button to work, I set autoReverse to true but it isn't doing anything. My second issue with the code is when the ellipse button is clicked the class MyEllipse isn't showing the ellipse shape like it is supposed to and it's not removing the circle animation from the pane. I tried to create a new pane in the EventHandler for the buttonellipse but I am assuming that isn't the correct way to do it. Any help on these two issues would be greatly appreciated.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class exam3b extends Application {
  @Override 
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {      
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle (0, 0, 25, 50);
rectangle.setFill(Color.ORANGE);

Circle circle = new Circle(115, 90, 45);
circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

PathTransition pt = new PathTransition();
pt.setDuration(Duration.millis(4000));
pt.setPath(circle);
pt.setNode(rectangle);
pt.setOrientation(
PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
pt.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
pt.setAutoReverse(false);
pt.play();

circle.setOnMousePressed(e -> pt.pause());
circle.setOnMouseReleased(e -> pt.play());

HBox panel = new HBox(10);
panel.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
Button button = new Button("Circle");
Button buttonellipse = new Button("Ellipse");
Button reverse = new Button("Reverse");
panel.getChildren().addAll(button,buttonellipse,reverse);

button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
{
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e)
    {
        reverse.setVisible(true);
    }
});

reverse.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() //supposed to make rectangle move in reverse direction
{
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e)
    {
        pt.setAutoReverse(true);
    }
});

buttonellipse.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() //button to make ellipse appear from class MyEllipse, reverse button is supposed to disappear
{
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e)
    {
        reverse.setVisible(false);
        Pane ellipse = new Pane();
        ellipse.getChildren().add(new MyEllipse());
    }
});

Pane pane = new Pane();
pane.getChildren().addAll(panel,circle,rectangle);

Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 350, 250);
primaryStage.setTitle("exam3b"); 
primaryStage.setScene(scene); 
primaryStage.show(); 
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
launch(args);
  }
}

 class MyEllipse extends Pane 
{
  private void paint() {
getChildren().clear();
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  Ellipse e1 = new Ellipse(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, 
    getWidth() / 2 - 50, getHeight() / 2 - 50);
  e1.setStroke(Color.color(Math.random(), Math.random(),
    Math.random()));
  e1.setFill(Color.WHITE);
  e1.setRotate(i * 180 / 16);
  getChildren().add(e1);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void setWidth(double width) {
super.setWidth(width);
paint();
  }

  @Override
  public void setHeight(double height) {
super.setHeight(height);
paint();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code has `pt.setAutoReverse(false);`.  I thought you said it was `true`?

Comment: @JoseMartinez yes, I set it to false in the original creation of the animation so that it wouldn't reverse but I set it to true in the EventHandler for the reverse button in hopes it would make the rectangle move in the opposite direction.

Comment: I ran your code and it does autoreverse when true.  I am working now on your other problem.

Comment: Please fix the intendation. Your code is extremely hard to read like this. Just copy &paste your formatted source code and use the editor functionality to turn the code into a code block.

Comment: @JoseMartinez It does autoreverse when true in the EventHandler? And wow thank you so much for the help, it is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You had an issue with how you were using MyEllipse, in that you were never adding it to your root pane nor were you settign the width/height (which leads to your paint method being called).  I renamed your root pane to 'root'.  Created an instance of 'MyEllipse', and in the 'Ellipse' button i add the instance of 'MyEllipse' to the root pane.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class exam3b extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 25, 50);
        rectangle.setFill(Color.ORANGE);

        Circle circle = new Circle(115, 90, 45);
        circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

        PathTransition pt = new PathTransition();
        pt.setDuration(Duration.millis(4000));
        pt.setPath(circle);
        pt.setNode(rectangle);
        pt.setOrientation(
                PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
        pt.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        pt.setAutoReverse(true);
        pt.play();

        circle.setOnMousePressed(e -> pt.pause());
        circle.setOnMouseReleased(e -> pt.play());

        HBox panel = new HBox(10);
        panel.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
        Button button = new Button("Circle");
        Button buttonellipse = new Button("Ellipse");
        Button reverse = new Button("Reverse");
        panel.getChildren().addAll(button, buttonellipse, reverse);

        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                reverse.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        reverse.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() //supposed to make rectangle move in reverse direction
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                pt.setAutoReverse(true);
            }
        });

        Pane root = new Pane();
        MyEllipse myEllipse = new MyEllipse();
        myEllipse.setWidth(200);
        myEllipse.setHeight(400);
        buttonellipse.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() //button to make ellipse appear from class MyEllipse, reverse button is supposed to disappear
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
//                reverse.setVisible(false);
                if (root.getChildren().contains(myEllipse)) {
                    root.getChildren().remove(myEllipse);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("adding ellipse");
                    root.getChildren().add(myEllipse);
                }
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(panel, circle, rectangle);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("exam3b");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class MyEllipse extends Pane {


    public MyEllipse() {
    }

    private void paint() {
        getChildren().clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            Ellipse e1 = new Ellipse(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2,
                    getWidth() / 2 - 50, getHeight() / 2 - 50);
            e1.setStroke(Color.color(Math.random(), Math.random(),
                    Math.random()));
            e1.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            e1.setStrokeWidth(1);
            e1.setRotate(i * 180 / 16);
            getChildren().add(e1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setWidth(double width) {
        super.setWidth(width);
        paint();
    }

    @Override
    public void setHeight(double height) {
        super.setHeight(height);
        paint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense. The only issue I am having now is when the ellipse button is clicked the circle animation is still in the background and the buttons are unable to be clicked once the ellipse is on the screen

Comment: THat wasnt'nt in your original question as a problem.  You will have to remove the circle.